# Crear un método para verificar que un String no esté vacío

Tags: java, string, validación

Quiero crear un método para validar un `String` que obtengo desde un `JOption`, quiero verificar que no esté vacío y no quiero repetir el código todo el tiempo, así que he pensado en crear un método para eso, que haga todo, que obtenga el `String` y lo verifique.

Quiero algo así:

```
name[i] = getString("Enter your Name:");
```

Pero tengo algo así:

```
for (int d = 0; d < 1; d++) {
    gender[i] = getString("Enter your Gender:");
    if (gender[i] == null || gender[i].trim().isEmpty()){
        Check();
        d--;
    }
}
```

He creado un método con lo siguiente pero no me funciona:

```
public static String getString(String Message) {
    String ans="";
    for (int u = 0; u<0; u++){
        ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Message);
        if (ans == null || ans.trim().isEmpty()){

            Check();
            u--;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Chris bienvenido/a a Stackoverflow. **Un proceso de validación es mucho más complicado de lo que uno puede creer**, algunas cosas se escapan. Existen librerías ya hechas, que te permiten hacer correctamente este tipo de cosas. En el caso que nos ocupa, la mejor librería es la [API StringUtils de Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). Una vez agregada la librería, puedes validar por ejemplo de esta forma: `if (StringUtils.isBlank(tuCadena)){ ...}`... La API tiene todo tipo de validación para cadenas (ver métodos en el enlace).

Comment: No sé que haga `Check()` pero creo que tienes un error de lógica. En la parte de `if (ans == null || ans.trim().isEmpty())` estás diciendo que si es nulo o si está vacío entra. La cosa es que, si entiendo correctamente, quieres lo contrario, que entre si NO está nulo ni vacío, ¿no es así? Si es correcto, cambialo a `if (ans != null && !ans.trim().isEmpty())`

Comment: u < 0? en el for

Comment: todo tu for no se deberia reemplazar por un while(flag)? donde flag se ponga en falso cuando realmente ingrese una cadena valida? y que hace check? nada? porque no regresa nada...

Answer (score 2):

Para Comparar string debes utilizar `Equals` que es la instriccion utilizada para comprar cadenas de string

Comment: Aquí no lo necesita, solo mira si es null o si está vacío

Comment: Puede utilizarlo para hacer cadena.Equals("") y con eso comprobaría si es una cadena vacía.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano claro que puedes utilizarlo para comparar si esta vacio ese metodo es utilizado para comparar y verificar string

Comment: ya, era un comentario respecto al comentario de @PabloLozano donde pone "Aquí no lo necesita", yo creo que sí, con equals se puede hacer

Comment: Se *puede* hacer, pero no es *necesario*. el método `isEmpty()` es más eficiente y cumple precisamente esa función.

Answer (score 2):

La forma habitual de verificar si una cadena es nula o no en Java es con la función `isEmpty()` que devuelve `true` o `false`
por ejemplo tengamos un metodo algo asi:

```
public boolean validarVacio(String cadena){
return cadena.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

para verificar por ejemplo, dándole click a un botón que obtenga el texto de un textfield

```
private void jBtn_AceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(validarVacio(txt_Cadena.getText())){
        System.out.println("vacio");
    }else{
        System.out.println("diferente de vacio");
    }
}
```

Lo que realiza el método `validarVacio` es retornar true o false, primero al parámetro que recibe de tipo `String` llamado `Cadena`, le elimina los espacios, con el metodo `.trim()` y posteriormente el método `.isEmpty()` verifica si la cadena esta vacía o no

Comment: Si cadena es null, esto lanzará un NPE. Si sabemos que la cadena nunca será null, entonces es válido

Comment: Comprobe los codigos haciendo una prueba en un proyecto pequeño y funciona, si el txt esta totalmente vacio, si se ponen varios espacios en el sigue funcionando, o a que te refieres con que si la cadena es null?

Answer (score 2):

Tan simple como crear la siguiente función:

```
public boolean isNull(Object valueField) {
        if (valueField == null || (valueField.getClass().equals(String.class) && ((String) valueField).isEmpty())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

De esa manera si es String sabes si es null o no, y es un código extensible con muy bajo acoplamiento.

Si lo quieres ver más claro, sustituye Object por String y elimina la comprobación de que la clase del valueField sea String y tendrás un código más simple.

Espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

## I. Respuesta corta

Si lo que quieres es verificar que la cadena no es nula y no está vacía, te propongo este código.

Se trata de un método que verificará la cadena que le pases en parámetro, devolviéndote un valor booleano: `true` o verdadero, si la cadena está en blanco o es nula; `false` o falso, si la cadena no está blanco y no es nula.)

Para verificar cualquier cadena, sólo tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```
if( !chkEmpty( tuCadena ) ){
    //No está vacía ni es nula
}
```

Este sería el código:

```
public static boolean chkEmpty( final String s ) {
  // Null-safe, short-circuit evaluation.
  return s == null || s.trim().isEmpty();
}
```

La función escrita así, te evitará el `Null Pointer Exception`, en caso de pasarle un valor nulo en parámetro.

Fuente: [Check whether a string is not null and not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3598792/5587982)

[Aquí puedes ver un Demo del código y hacer pruebas](http://rextester.com/PVNJ21454).

**Nota:** Si quieres hacer más validaciones, considera la segunda parte de la respuesta.

---

## II. Más sobre *validar*

Un proceso de validación es mucho más complicado de lo que uno puede creer. En el caso concreto de una cadena, implicaría al menos verificar:

- que no está en blanco
- que no es nula.
- que no empieza con un espacio en blanco,
- que no tiene múltiples espacios en blanco en su contenido
- que usa una codificación adecuada
- etc, etc

Existen librerías ya hechas, que te permitirán validar realmente una cadena. En el caso que nos ocupa, una de las mejores librería es la [API StringUtils de Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). Una vez agregada la librería, puedes validar por ejemplo de esta forma: `if (StringUtils.isBlank(tuCadena)){ ...}`

La API tiene todo tipo de validación para cadenas (ver métodos en el enlace).

Otra posibilidad sería crear **tu propia clase de validación de cadenas**, en la que incluyas los diferentes métodos de validación que necesites para la aplicación que estás desarrollando.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71790/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-crear-un-metodo-para-verificar-que-un-string-n).